# Is consciousness (as we perceive it) what really separates us from animals?

Tags: consciousness, evolution

The last couple of weeks or even months, I'm thinking a lot about consciousness.
I have some ideas I would really like to discuss with some open minded, philosophical people. And in the search for what to start with I thought this would be a good idea.

Looking forward to your answers.

Edit:

Since it isn't clear what I mean by consciousness. Which isn't really a suprise as there is no concrete definition yet.

I contemplate that consciousness is us being aware of being and able to think phylosophically and decide on our actions and thoughts. Which is not to say, other animals couldn't do that. I just think they don't do, yet. 
From what I observed and read until now, it is totally possible, and I think likely, that all actions animals take are instinct or sub-conscious. Meaning, they aren't able to decide. Altough it may look like it sometimes.

I accepted Slup's answer. Because, in the end SE is still a Q&A site. I love all your answers, they give a nice, wide perspective. Slup's just rings with me the most.

Thank you everyone

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Consciousness is generally understood not to require use and analysis of language and is generally accepted to [occur by degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness#Assessment). Zen Buddhists chase forms of consciousness that might be understood as prelinguistic. Animals, such as [Kanzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanzi) even have the ability to manipulate symbols, though they lack a true language, and there is a branch of ethology called [cognitive ethology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_ethology). The cognitive difference among apes is one of degree.

Comment: It seems you have spent no time observing animal behaviour. I would suggest following up on JD's comment and looking into Zen or more generally mysticism. Elsewhere consciousness is little studied, just brains and behaviour. Perhaps you could start with some youtube talks by people like Rupert Spira. .  . .

Comment: I don’t know the answer to your question. Christianity (at least as religion) wanted to make a big separation between man and animal.  Since many more people in the West are now non-believers,  I think we will begin to get a more honest appraisal of the intelligence of animals in the future.

Comment: @JD i still don't see how we would be able to know how animals experience life until we are able to somehow experience what they do. And as long as we can't do that, I think everything we conceptualise is speculation. I will look into what you've posted though. I want this to be a discussion, not an argument. Hence why I posted it in philosophy.

Comment: @Gordon, definitely. It's happening already. Yet intelligence doesn't mean consciousness and vice-versa.

Comment: It seems to me that some animals, like the elephant, may have consciousness, maybe some parrots too, but I am not a scientist or anything like an expert.

Comment: @Gordon no worries. When we are honest to ourselves we have no fricking clue what and how consciousness is. And who or what has it or not. We can only say for sure what we experience, in that subject.

Comment: @Sens This is the [problem of other minds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_other_minds). There are epistemological and ontological tools other than rational and phenomenological reflection. _Homo sapiens_ and _Pan troglodytes_ both use symbols. The case can be made that your private consciousness is not unique in the universe. Solipsism is interesting, but not very pragmatic.

Comment: If you have doubts, start out with [Chimpanzee Politics: Power and Sex Among Apes](https://books.google.com/books?id=PaTkhYwi5bwC&pg=PT1&dq=politics+chimps&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw9qbOloHnAhUZa80KHdAWAjgQ6AEwBXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=politics%20chimps&f=false). I think you'll find the line between human and chimp politicians blurry.

Comment: @JD thank you again!

Comment: @Sens Anything for a fellow traveler down the rabbit hole of thought. The SEP has a good (free) article on [animal cognition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cognition-animal/). When you're ready for a challenge, move beyond representational and computational metaphors of mind to an enactive metaphor as in [embodied cognition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/embodied-cognition/). Why settle for the central nervous system when you can incorporate the peripheral one and the endocrine system more broadly!

Comment: I must admit to being baffled as to why anyone would think other animals are not conscious. Where is the scientific evidence? Where is any evidence of any kind?

Comment: @PeterJ again. I didn't say I believe that. I'm saying the same you do. You can neither prove nor disprove any speculations we have about consciousness in animals.

Comment: @Sens - I was just asking generally.

Comment: @PeterJ True. It's also weird to me how anyone can go to hard assumptions about that. We frankly can't and probably never can know. It's still an interesting thought experiment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am aware of at most one serious falsifiable attempt of constructing theory of consciousness beyond the usual, mostly not falsifiable discussions in the philosophy of mind. I am speaking about [integrated information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory). The main authors of IIT are [Christof Koch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christof_Koch) and [Gulio Tononi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giulio_Tononi). They wrote interesting popularization books on the subject, that contain no mathematical details, but with lots of information concerning neuroscientific research, that supports IIT.

IIT defines a quantity that measures a degree of consciousness exhibited by the system. This quantity is called **phi**.

IIT predicts that not only certain animal brains (mammals included) support consciousness with substantial **phi's**, but even some not very complex artificial neural nets have nonzero **phi's**, although feedforward neural nets and von Neumann architecture computers have **phi** equal to zero.

For a mathematically detailed presentation of the theory in which some toy examples are presented c.f. [the paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4014402/pdf/pcbi.1003588.pdf). For an even more rigorous mathematical treatment c.f. [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.03627.pdf).

Comment: That sounds interesting I will have a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There is really no doubt that animals have consciousness in the basic sense of the terms. They are aware of the world around them and respond to it: avoiding threats, consuming food, seeking out others of their kind... There's a more difficult question as to whether animals have a sense of *self*. Higher animals seem to, since they can order themselves into organized activities and communities — e.g., the fact that a dog can learn commands to work effectively with a human suggests that the dog is aware of its own *role* with respect to the human, which implies self-awareness — but that argument becomes more difficult to make for simpler animals.

What sets humans apart is our capacity for symbolic expression. Wolves can organize into a hunting pack just by observing each other and picking up cues to each other's behavior. Humans can plan out strategies, teach each other useful skills, assign rules and roles... all because we develop sets of symbols by which we pass such information.

Comment: I think animals have sub-consciousness in the form of instincts. I don't think they have a consciouseness they are aware of. Being able to think about ourselves and being itself, is what really makes us different. Is what I think. Not to say animals have no self. Many surely react on being an indivdiual. But can we say that is really self-awareness, or just memory and instinct?

Comment: @Sens — 'Consciousness' is usually used in the sense of 'awareness'; all living creatures have that. What you're talking about is *self*-awareness (*self*-consciousness), and there is evidence that at least some animals have an awareness of self. Hunting dogs an instinct to hunt, sure, but they do not have an instinct to follow human commands. That is something they learn to do, and learning to take a particular role suggests that there is a concept of 'self' that can be put in relation to an 'other'.

Comment: Does it though? That is the question. Are animals really aware of being or is everything they do just instinct or sub-conscious. We have no way to know. Do we?
Even being able to train dogs doesn't mean anything neccessarily. Usually we train them by giving them food for doing something we want. So they only thing they actually learn is, if I do this I get something I want. Which is probaly the most basic form of instinct.

Comment: Also, does being able to differentiate between you and I really mean you are aware?

Comment: @Sens — There is no sense talking about instincts unless the thing with instincts is aware. A creature cannot run away from a predator unless it is aware that another creature is near, and able to distinguish the other as a threat. A creature cannot satisfy the instinct to feed or mate if it cannot identify food and other members of its species. Instincts are *responses*, and one must be conscious of a stimulus in order to have a response.

Comment: What about machines, especially robots? They receive a certain signal(stimulus) and if they are programmed for that they will respond(instinct).
No consciousness needed. I don't want to say that living organsims are no better than machines. But this example shows my point best.

Comment: @Sens — Robots cannot evaluate stimuli (and in particular, they cannot evaluate *novel* stimuli). Give an incorrect input to a machine, and it will stall or crash; it won't adapt the way a sophisticated animal will.  I'm not saying that robots could not eventually reach a level of consciousness; I'm saying that the comparison falls well short of the mark.

Comment: or it can just ignore it and go on as before. But I probably didn't think that through too well. I'm neither denying nor saying that animals have a consciousness like we do. That's why I wanted to discuss. I think we don't have the means to know, maybe we'll never have.

Answer (score 3):

I think anybody who is interested in this subject must first explore scientific studies of animal behaviour.

In my opinion, there are studies which show that even animals have at least an under-developed consciousness.

Evolutionary biologists may argue that neo-Drawinism (DNA mutations + natural selection) can also explain these advanced behaviours and therefore it is not necessary to hypothesize that animals have kind of a primitive consciousness.

But I do not think that neuroscience supports the belief that there is a special reason that only human brain can give rise to consciousness and animal brains are void of consciousness.

Comment: Hi ! I think it's fair to point out that a 'kind of a primitive consciousness' is probably not what the OP intends by 'consciousness as we perceive' or experience it. Otherwise I agree with your answer - and, of course, I welcome you to PSE.

Comment: I'm with @GeoffreyThomas. Altough I'm not sure if animals have any kind of awareness of consciousness. As all their behaviour could be instinct as well I think.
So they probalby have sub-conscious. I think what makes us different is awareness of being. 
Thank you for the welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

During my sociology study we were reading about a sociologist, philosopher and psychologist George Herbert Mead (1863-1931), who proposed that conciousness is a form of behaviour. He argued that a person's personality consisting of self-awareness and self-image, is a product of social experience. I found this a very interesting perspective to think about.

Comment: That's the kind of direction my thoughts are going into as well. Humans stopped or severely slowed down evolution in their bodies through civilization and medicine. But looking at global development you could find that evolution went over to our social behaviour. In turn I cam to the conclusion that our consciousness may be just evolution working in real-time instead of generations.